# How many reputation points are needed in order to remove a question ban?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

A few weeks ago, I got blocked from asking questions. Since then, I gained almost 200 reputation points putting me in the top 4% contributors in the last month, gaining 204 points in a month.

From the block page:

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines
>   that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were
>   poorly received.

My question is: how many good deeds do you need to do to get Stack Overflow to forgive your sins?

Comment: Congratulations on being in the top 4% of contributors in the last month. Unfortunately, that simply demonstrates your ability to *answer* questions, not *ask* them. Reputation is not a measure of how well you can ask questions (or your writing skills in general).

Comment: @BoltClock, I understand that. But, the only way to "positively contribute" is attempting to answer questions and trying to reopen the case for my bad question, which I already did. What else is considered "positive contributions"?

Comment: No, that's not the only way. One other way is to improve your existing questions - have you tried that yet? That is the best chance you have, because it deals with the issue the question ban is primarily concerned with after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We don't know the details of the algorithm, but gaining 200 points on answers is a step in the right direction. As BoltClock mentioned, work on improving some of your other questions, and make sure you provide details for the one that's unanswered.

Also, I reopened one that I thought was incorrectly closed as "too broad."

Note that once the ban is lifted, you'll still be close to the borderline, so don't stop working to improve your posts. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for re-opening a question. The issue here is even if you modify a question which probably was not well-stated, (and eventually badly received), and you vote for re-opening...You still have to wait for someone with "super-power" to vote for re-opening the question, correct?

Comment: @Samer You do have to wait for other people to vote to reopen your question once you edit it. Anyone with enough reputation to vote to close can also vote to reopen.

Comment: According to Mr. Owl, it takes precisely three licks to get to the tootsie roll center of a tootsie pop. If you've honestly done all you can and still can't quite get out from under it, [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) and we'll have a look.