# How many deleted questions do I have?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I can see that I've got [one -5 question deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049464/undeclared-identifier-idhttp), but I'm interested in any others which I can't view.

I've been question blocked (probably because of the -5 post) and am not sure where to go now.

[There is a post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which gives the following information:

> ### What can I do to release the ban?
>
> **Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**

As the advice said [I edited my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2808510/tim?tab=activity&sort=revisions), but this being Stack Overflow, I doubt that any will be seen, and almost certainly not upvoted. They're not terrible questions, but they're not amazing either, and there's not much that can be done to make them amazing - they're simple issues encountered by a beginner, which doesn't interest anyone here.

---

I guess the next thing to do is to try and answer questions, but [that also doesn't do much](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268948/2808510). Also, I'm slow and not especially knowledgeable so that's not really a solution.

---

So my main question - do I have any deleted questions, and can I do anything about them. If not, what can I do?

Comment: You have 3 deleted questions - the one you've mentioned - one from May (-2) and another (-5 and closed) from Nov 2014.

Comment: @JonClements Anything I can do or is it a wait for votes?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to take notice of the comments you received on the latest deleted question and see if you can't act on those to improve it.,,

Comment: @JonClements Could that get it undeleted? I'm not sure I can, I don't think I have the project any more.

Comment: If you wanted to - you could post the link to the most recent -5 (I believe you're making a genuine attempt here) and see if the community wishes to cast their undelete votes... the "meta effect" could go either way though - so it'd be your choice to do so

Comment: @JonClements I may do that, let me think. I've seen meta both ways in the past. I genuinely like to contribute here and am researching past advice. Thanks for the time you've taken to help here.

Comment: You can edit a question that has been deleted. You have a link to one of the questions, and Jon or another diamond mod can probably provide you with a link to the others if they're not accessible in your profile. Only take the Meta gamble *after* you've edited them into shape. I'm not going to undelete a question in hopes that you'll whack it into shape, but I will undelete one that you've already whacked into shape. :-)